# Not allowed to load local resource: file:///android_asset/... with Crosswalk 16+

Tags: android, crosswalk, xwebview

I have Android project with Crosswalk 16.45.421.19.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

I have index.html

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <base href="/">
    <link rel="icon" href="img/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
</head>

<body>
    <img src="file:///android_asset/img/logo.png">
    <img src="file:///android_asset/img/preloaderWhite.gif">
    <div id="my-app">Привет!!!!</div>
</body>

</html>
```

```
xWalkWebView.load("file:///android_asset/index.html", null);  //All works!
```

When this file is on the server:

```
xWalkWebView.load("http://192.168.0.102/", null); //Get index.html, but images don't load.
```

And:

```
Not allowed to load local resource: file:///android_asset/img/logo.png"
```

Answer (score -1):

Hello check this thing out CSP content security policies https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Security/CSP i believe this is your topic

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes

Comment: Link-only answers are generally [frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/204922) on Stack Overflow. In time it is possible for links to atrophy and become unavailable, meaning that your answer is useless to users in the future. It would be best if you could provide the general details of your answer in your actual post, citing your link as a reference.